# Tensor notation of covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, notation

I'm trying to apply Wald's General Relativity equation $3.1.14$:

$$\nabla_a{T^{b_1\dots b_k}}_{c_1\dots c_{\ell}}=\overline{\nabla}_a{T^{b_1\dots b_k}}_{c_1\dots c_{\ell}}+\sum_i{C^{b_i}}_{ad}{T^{b_1\dots d\dots b_k}}_{c_1\dots c_{\ell}}-\sum_j{C^d}_{ac_j}{T^{b_1\dots b_{\ell}}}_{c_1\dots d\dots c_{\ell}}$$

to the covariant derivative of a 2-form, and I'm having trouble understanding what the notation "$\dots d\dots$" means.

I am familiar with Einstein's summation convention. What is unclear to me is what is the position of the "$d$" index. Does any position work?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$d$ is just the summed (dummy) index. In words, the procedure would be as follows: in the first summation, replace an upper index in $T$ with $d$, and use the replaced index in the object $C$, along with the lower dummy index $d$ to sum over. The final lower index of $C$ is always the index from the covariant derviative $\nabla$. You repeat this until you've covered *all* the upper indices in $T$. E.g. the simplest case for a vector is just
$$ \nabla_a T^b = \bar{\nabla}_a T^b + C^b{}_{ad} T^d \ . $$
And then you can work out the analogous procedure for the lower indices of $T$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it doesn't matter which specific index you choose to sum over?

Comment: Yes, $d$ here could be any other letter (that's not already used). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: Sorry, I might not be explaining myself properly. I mean, out of all of the b1,b2,...bl, I can choose whichever I want to replace with d?

Comment: Ah ok. You can choose any but you have to go through all the $b_i$'s individually. So it makes sense to start with replacing the first index, then the second, etc. So you'll get terms like $T^{d \, b_2 \, b_3 ...}$, $T^{b_1 \, d \, b_3 ...}$, all the way to $T^{... b_{k-1} \, d}$,

Comment: I get it now, many thanks!